# "Warning: Indexing with colon as row will create a copy in the future" in using DataFrames in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

When I try to extract a column from a DataFrame in Julia, I get the following error:

> julia> datecol = df[:, :time]
>   ┌ Warning: Indexing with colon as row will create a copy in the future. Use `df[col_inds]` to get the columns without copying
>   │   caller = top-level scope at none:0
>   └ @ Core none:0
>   5000-element
>   Array{String,1}:
>    "2002-11-27T22:00:00.000000Z"
>    "2002-11-28T22:00:00.000000Z"
>   .
>   .
>   .

BUT, when I perform `df[:time]` no warning gets produced.

Can someone please shed light on the difference between `df[:, :time]` and `df[:time]`? Does each perform fundamentally different operations???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please update DataFrames.jl to the current release and you will not get this warning.

Now what is the difference:

- `df[col]` returns you the column `col` in a `DataFrame` `df` as it is stored there (no copying is performed - you get access to the vector stored in `df`)
- `df[:, col]` returns you the copy of a column `col` in a `DataFrame`

The behavior is similar to writing `x` vs `x[:]` when `x` is a vector in Julia.

For completeness of the exposition if `df` were a `SubDataFrame` then:

- `df[col]` returns you the the appropriate view of column `col` in the parent `DataFrame` of ``` df``df ```)
- `df[:, col]` returns you the copy of a view returned by `df[col]` (i.e. a normal vector - not a view)

In short - use `x = df[col]` if you want that changing values of `x` propagate back to `df` and use `x = df[:, col]` if you want a freshly allocated object whose changes will not propagate back to `df`.

Comment: Thanks Bogumil! Terse and concise answer - as always! I would not have a clue in updating DaraFrams.jl. You are a legend, mate.